# Morphological closing using java

Tags: java, image-processing, morphological-analysis

I am trying to use this source code to do a morphologial closing on an image (with canny edge detected) 
https://code.google.com/p/doccrop/source/browse/DocCrop/src/imageanalysis/morphology/Closing.java?r=3

I've created an instance of Closing and I've applied it on a BufferedImage and then draw it but I get a black image as a result!! 
At first I had an error saying that the image must be type_byte_gray so I used this to change type but I guess it doesn't work

```
      BufferedImage img1= ImageIO.read(new File(path));
  BufferedImage imge = new BufferedImage(img1.getHeight(),img1.getWidth(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
```

Comment: Has it been verified that the code you posted a link to actually works?

Comment: Well no but the author seemed very confident :) Anyway it's easy to do the closing operation with matlab (imclose) but I need to do it with java ! Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, run it step-by-step under debugger and see whether execution flow and intermediate values make sense.

Comment: The code you show looks wrong...why you have two bufferedimage? "img1" holds the input image this is true. But "imge" is just a emtpy grayscale image of the size of "img1". Please show mor code.

Comment: The empty grayscale image really explain why it is black.....

Comment: So how can change image type to TYPE_Byte_Gray ? I added that line when I was trying to convert image type .. I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You might use an image processing framework, like [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/) or [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/), for such purpose, as shown below.

**input:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

**source code:**

```
import marvin.image.MarvinColorModelConverter;
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;
import marvin.io.MarvinImageIO;
import marvin.math.MarvinMath;
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

public class ClosingDemo {

    public ClosingDemo(){
        MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/closingIn.png");
        image = MarvinColorModelConverter.rgbToBinary(image, 127);
        morphologicalClosing(image.clone(), image, MarvinMath.getTrueMatrix(60, 60));
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/closingOut.png");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClosingDemo();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method by adding marvin framework into the library work but I get an error saying saying that the path of \marvin\plugins\image\org.marvinproject.image.morphological.closing.jar  in not found ! I added closing.jar but still the same! can you please tell me what should I do? This is the first time I use Marvin  framework

Comment: To use Marvin you need to copy the "marvin" folder into your project directory. Take a look at the tutorial "2. First Application" at the tutorial section of the project website. There is also a video called "Configuring the development environment". In the case of any problem, you can use the discussion group.

Comment: Yes, Now with this example it works fine but with my image it gives me a black image! my image is black with white edges should I invert the colors? and how can I do that with marvin ?